# Apply customized width to a prime-ng p-column in html template in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I want to apply a different width to each column of my columns using [style] as shown in the example, I tried `[style]="{'width.px':'column.length + 10'}"` but column.length isn't working on the template, below an example of my template

```
<p-column *ngFor="let column of columns"
        [field]="column"
        [header]="label[column] ? label[column] : column"
        [style]="{'width.px':'column.length + 10'}"></p-column>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
 [style]="{'width': column.length + 'px'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is generally not a good idea to put a lot of evaluations in the template :

In your component you can map your columns and do your calculations there, assuming columns is and array of objects . You map and add a new property columnWidth  where you do your do your evaluations.

```
//assuming you have an array of objects.
    var columns = [
      {
      id : 1},
      {id: 2},
      {id :3}
    ];


        var columnWithExtraProperty = columns.map( (column : any) => {
          return{
            ...column,
            columnWidth : column.length  + 10 + 'px'
          }

        });

       // console.log(columnWithExtraProperty);
```

Then try this in the template :

```
<p-column *ngFor="let column of columnWithExtraProperty"
        [field]="column"
        [header]="label[column] ? label[column] : column"
        [style]="{'width.px':column.columnWidth}"></p-column>
```

Comment: thanks, but I can't do this as my data comes in an array from the back, and contains more than 200 rows (sometimes more and other times less, so I don't know how to map)

Comment: I have just given you an example of how to map!  Take the data that comes from your backend( ie columns) and run the map on it adding a new property you can use in your template.

Comment: find more simple: [style]="{'width.px': +(column.length)+20}

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution which isn't perfect, but for me, it answers to the problem:

```
[style]="{'width.px': +(column.length)+20}"
```

The '+' sign is there to convert value to a number (I tried putting Number(column) which didn't work here) - it is weird. I think this is happening, because `column.length` suppose to be a number, and I added 20 px for margin the text.